# Precedence of EJB Deployment Descriptors

Tags: java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, websphere-8, deployment-descriptor

If I have an EJB packaged in a WAR because it is exposed as a REST web service, according to [this link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cejb_ejbinwar.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-10-3-0-1&lang=en), I need to have the ejb-*.xml files at the root of the WEB-INF directory. My current environment is Websphere 8.5 and EJB 3.1

If I later add multiple EJBs ( in separate EJB projects ) in the same application and define its deployment descriptors in the respective projects, those seem to be ignored.   It appears that ALL of my descriptors should be defined in the descriptors in the WEB-INF directory - or in other words, it seems that I should augment the descriptors in WEB-INF directory even for EJBs that are defined as separate projects.

Is this how it needs to be or am I missing something that is forcing me to do this?  I could not find any documentation explaining this part.

**More Details:**
This is how my application.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
 version="7">
<display-name>MyApp</display-name>
<module id="Module_1395346343165">
    <web>
        <web-uri>MyWeb.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>myapp</context-root>
    </web>
 </module>
 <module id="Module_1395346304194">
    <ejb>ejb1.jar</ejb> 
 </module>
 <module id="Module_1424684968934">
    <ejb>ejb2.jar</ejb>
 </module>
 <module id="Module_1431010943758">
    <ejb>ejb3.jar</ejb>
 </module>
</application>
```

The ejb1 is the one that will live in the webapp.    The other two, ejb2 and ejb3 are separate ejb projects that are supposed to be in EAR's root.

Comment: May be you missing descriptors specific to your application server.

Comment: Not sure, I understand what you mean.  I have all the descriptors defined in the separate projects but they seem to be trumped by the ones in WEB-INF directory of the WAR.  I am trying to keep them ( the descriptors )  independent since they are different EJBs.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate EJB projects"?  What does your actual deployment artifact look like?  Are these separate EJB projects ending up as .jar in WEB-INF/lib/ of your WAR?  If yes, then that's working as expected: per the EJB 3.1 spec, ejb-jar.xml files in .jar in WEB-INF/lib/ are ignored, and only WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml is used.

Comment: I am adding edits for the application.xml to the question.  From the link I have in the question, I realise that for EJBs to be used in webapp, that is how it needs to be.   But to answer your question, These separate EJB projects are not going to end up as jars in WEB-INF/lib of the WAR but will be the jars at the root of the EAR.

Comment: @bkail - Also from the same link, if I have the 2 different EJBs associated with 2 different WARs in the same EAR, then their information would be in the respective WAR's WEB-INF, so I am even more unclear, for the EJB that would not be part of the WAR, where should its binding files live?

Comment: @adbdkb What do you mean by "associated with 2 different WARs"?  For an EJB JAR module outside a WAR, the files go in META-INF.  So, `.ear!/ejb1.jar!/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml`, `.ear!/ejb1.jar!/META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` and so on.

Comment: @bkail - By "associated", I mean they are part of that WAR.  Your last comment is what I was looking for a confirmation for.  It validates the understanding I had.   Can you put it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @adbdkb Sure, done.  Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EJBs in a WAR module, the files go in `WEB-INF`, so `.ear!/MyWeb.war!/ejb-jar.xml`, `.ear!/MyWeb.war!/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`, etc.

For EJBs in separator EJB modules outside a WAR, the files go in `META-INF`. So, `.ear!/ejb1.jar!/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml`, `.ear!/ejb1.jar!/META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`, etc.